# How to open and paste a new table everytime in an already existing word document in Apache poi?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ms-word, apache-poi

There is already an existing word document with the header and footer and some text in the front page. The body of the word document is empty. I need to create a table everytime (or overwrite the previous)which is in the second page of the word document. I am creating a table from scratch and trying the update the word document. However I am getting an error. Below is my code

```
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(source
                                                        + "Testword.docx"));

    //create table
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

    //create first row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
    tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

    //create second row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
    tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

    //create third row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
    tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");


    document.write(new FileOutputStream(source
                                        + "Testword.docx")); // This line is generating an error
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\Testword.docx");
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
    is.close();

    //create table
    XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

    //create first row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
    tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
    tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");

    //create second row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
    tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
    tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");

    //create third row
    XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
    tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
    tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");


    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Testword.docx");

    document.write(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: This will create a new document everytime. I need to create a table in an already existing word document.

Comment: I made some changes:
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\Testword.docx");
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
        is.close();

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! I did not do the input stream before

Comment: . close() needs to remember to modify in finally {}